# To display data which has least count

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the details of the resort like resort name and town name that has the least bedroom count. I tried this piece of code -

```
select r.resortname, r.townname
from resort r, cabin c 
where r.resortid = c.resortid
and c.bedroomcount = (select min(sum(c1.bedroomcount)) from cabin c1 group by c1.resortid)
order by r.resortname;
```

But this code is not returning me any output or error.

Please help with this, thanks in advance! :)

I found the right answer-

```
select r.resortname, r.townname
from resort r, cabin c
where r.resortid = c.resortid
and c.bedroomcount = (select min(min(bedroomcount)) from cabin c1 group by c1.bedroomcount)
order by r.resortname;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions . . . and `JOIN`:

```
select r.resortname, r.townname
from resort r join
     (select c.*,
             rank() over (partition by resortid order by bedroomcount asc) as seqnum
      from cabin c 
     ) c
     on r.resortid = c.resortid and
        c.seqnum = 1
order by r.resortname;
```

Comment: This code just works like the code below, `select r.resortname, r.townname
from resort r inner join cabin c 
on r.resortid = c.resortid 
where c.bedroomcount in (select min(bedroomcount) from cabin c1 group by c1.resortid)
order by r.resortname;` It outputs all the resort names whereas it should output only one resort name which has the least value.

Comment: @yaminir . . . The `r.bedroomcount = c.min_bedroomcount` should only choose the minimum bedroom count.

Comment: There is no `bedroomcount` in `r` table, it only exists in `c` table. So there it showed an error.

Comment: @yaminir . . . That makes sense.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show resorts, so select from the resorts table. You want the one(s) with the minimum bedroom count, so apply an appropriate where clause.

```
select resortname, townname
from resort
where resortid in
(
  select resortid
  from cabin
  group by resortid
  order by sum(bedroomcount)
  fetch first row with ties
);
```

The `FETCH FIRST` clause is available as of Oracle 12c.